# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit/2'

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, angular-route-segment

I have a simple app working with angular4, but I got the following error:

```
 :1440 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit/2'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit/2'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1719)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (router.js:1684)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
```

This is the structure of the project  :

```
--src
    --app
        --views
            --admin
                --GestionProjects
                     --projects
                           --edit-projects
                                 --edit-project.component.ts
                                 --edit-project.component.html
                           --projects.component.ts
                           --projects.component.html
                     --new-project
                           --new-project.component.ts
                           --new-project.component.html
                     --project.module.ts
                     --project-routing.module.ts
```

this is the file app.routing.ts

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Import Containers
import {
  FullLayoutComponent,
  SimpleLayoutComponent
} from './containers';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'pages',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [

      {
        path: 'GestionProject',
        loadChildren: './views/Admin/GestionProjects/projet.module#ProjetModule'
      } 

    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'pages',
    component: SimpleLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Pages'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './views/pages/pages.module#PagesModule',
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

the file project-routing.module.ts :

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {ProjectsComponent} from './projects/projects.component';
import {NewProjectsComponent} from './new-projects/new-projects.component';
import {EditProjectComponent} from './projects/edit-project/edit-project.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'Projects'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'list',
        component: ProjectsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'List of projects'
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'edit/:id',
            component : EditProjectComponent,
            data : {
              title: 'editer a project'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        component : NewProjectsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'add a new project'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class ProjetRoutingModule {}
```

the file project.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ProjetService} from '../../../../../service/projet.service';
import {Projet} from '../../Models/Projet';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  pageProjects:any;
  pages:Array<number>;

  constructor(private router:Router,
              private projetSevice:ProjetService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

        this.projetSevice.getProjects()
          .subscribe(data=>{
            this.pageProjects=data;
          },err=>{
            console.log('this is error');
          })
  }

  Edit(id:number){
    this.router.navigate(['edit',id]);
  }

  delete(p:Projet){
      let confirm = window.confirm('are you sur .. ');
      if(confirm==true){
        this.projetSevice.deleteProject(p.id)
          .subscribe(data=>{
            this.pageProjects.splice(
              this.pageProjects.indexOf(p),1
            );
          },err=>{
            console.log(err);
          })
      }
  }

}
```

and finnaly the file project.component.html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Numéro</th>
          <th>Intitulé</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr *ngFor="let c of pageProjects">
          <td>{{c.id}}</td>
          <td>{{c.intitule}}</td>
          <td>{{c.description}}</td>
          <td><a (click)="delete(c)">delete</a> <a (click)="Edit(c.id)">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
```

i have another file called _nav.ts :

```
 export const navigation = [
  {
    name: 'Tableau de bord',
    url: '/dashboard',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',
  },
{
    name: 'Projets',
    url: '/GestionProjects',
    icon: 'icon-puzzle',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'List of projects',
        url: '/list',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      },
      {
        name: 'add a new project',
        url: '/add',
        icon: 'icon-puzzle'
      }

    ]
  },
}
```

that i call in a file that presents the side-nav bar :

[image]

everything goes well getting the list of the projects i want but when i click on edit i get the error above rror: Cannot match any routes ...

help please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying to navigate to the absolute URL, that will take you to

```
  localhost/#/edit/2 // which not found
```

you have to use relative navigation to the current route

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

this.router.navigate(['edit',id], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Comment: thank you for your help , i don't get this error again , but i have another problem while clicking on edit with id=2 for exemple i get this url : // http://localhost:4200/#/GestionProject/list;0=edit;1=2  // why it's like this  ? i was waiting for somthing like http://localhost:4200/#/GestionProject/list/edit/2 , and i don't get the result of the page editComponent.html , what should i do ? thank you in advance

Comment: i've updated my answer, use this.router.navigate(['edit',id], { relativeTo: this.route }); instead of [['edit',id]]

Comment: thank you so much for your help !! , it works now :)

Comment: @FatehMohamed can you please add some information what's the use of `relativeTo` here?

Comment: @FatehMohamed brother i have another problem , i think i have a problem with the structure of the children in  project-routing.module.ts  , i get an error : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null , i can't get the result of the page edit-component.html after click on edit of any the project

Comment: you are missing a component here : path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'Projects'
    }, you have to add a component like this : path:'', component: someCompoent, data: {} ...

Comment: @FatehMohamed , but i don't have any other component , should i create one ? if you mean a component that containts inside a template with router link etc .. i can't use it becaus i'm already using the file _nav.ts that shows the nav side bar as i mention in the post .